# Power automate web. How extract the filename from the Content-Disposition headers

Tags: power-automate

I need to get the file name Daily_Test.csv from the headers of my HTTP action.
I have a (Compose - Extract File Name from Headers) after the (HTTP - Download File) action.
Then I will save it to a variable, but I'm not having luck getting the file name.

for (HTTP - Download File) action (Show raw outputs)

```
{
"statusCode": 200,
"headers": {
    "Date": "Thu, 01 Feb 2024 03:59:57 GMT",
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=31557600, private",
    "Pragma": "max-age=31557600",
    "X-Robots-Tag": "noindex,nofollow",
    "aroflo-server": "web02-2018",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "Content-Type": "application/csv",
    "Expires": "Fri, 31 Jan 2025 03:59:57 GMT",
    "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=\"Daily_Test.csv\"",
    "Content-Length": "32"
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a header:

```
outputs('HTTP_-_Download_File')?['headers/Content-Disposition']
```

To get Filename:

```
split(
  outputs('HTTP_-_Download_File')?['headers/Content-Disposition'],
  '"'
)?[1]
```

Comment: Hi Sam
I got this when trying to save.

The input parameter(s) of action 'Compose' contain an invalid reference to 'HTTP_-_Download_File)'. Correct to include a valid reference to 'HTTP_-_Download_File)' for the input parameter(s) of action 'Compose'.

Comment: Update your question with a screen grab of the flow step that gets the file. Or try again now with the updated answer, (had a typo).

Comment: just running a new test now added images

Comment: There is no text in the output of a linked message with Clink to Download. I copied the link, and it is below.
"https://prod-10.australiasoutheast.logic.azure.com/workflows/5e814b65aaa54e7991e476f0fa84b62c/runs/08584948360513332458737558506CU20/actions/Compose/contents/ActionOutputs?api-version=2017-07-01&se=2024-02-01T11%3A00%3A00.0000000Z&sp=%2Fruns%2F08584948360513332458737558506CU20%2Factions%2FCompose%2Fcontents%2FActionOutputs%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=gdJszEZtSdpq7d1Spz8MqJ7ksXxuwpE6zpXXlsF08nc"

Comment: Try the last option in the updated answer. Failing that, try the very first one to see if you are able to get the header.

Comment: The last option returned. 
Daily_Test.csv
Nice work, man 

Comment: sweet - please help mark the answer as Accepted (the checkmark beneath the vote buttons) for the benefit of all.